# In a small script to monitor a folder for new files, the script seems to be finding the wrong files

Tags: bash, inotify

I'm using this script to monitor the downloads folder for new `.bin` files being created. However, it doesn't seem to be working. If I remove the grep, I can make it copy any file created in the Downloads folder, but with the grep it's not working. I suspect the problem is how I'm trying to compare the two values, but I'm really not sure what to do.

```
#!/bin/sh

downloadDir="$HOME/Downloads/"
mbedDir="/media/mbed"

inotifywait -m --format %f -e create $downloadDir -q | \
while read line; do
    if [ $(ls $downloadDir -a1 | grep '[^.].*bin' | head -1) == $line ]; then
        cp "$downloadDir/$line" "$mbedDir/$line"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I'm not clear on what it's supposed to be doing.  What's the purpose of the comparison?  As written, it seems to only copy the file if it's the first (alphabetically) file containing "bin" (not necessarily ending in "bin", because the grep pattern isn't anchored to the end of the line).

Comment: 2. things, 1. always surround variables of an unknown nature with db-quotes, i.e. `"$line"` If you wind up with a space in value for `$line` that can break things, 2. turn on the shell debugging, i.e. `set -vx` above your while loop. Then you will see each line/block of code AND then the values that assigned to each of the variables. Then it is easy to see where these are failing. If you can't figure it out, edit your post to include relavent debugging output. Good luck.

Comment: @GordonDavisson The purpose of the comparison is to only move files matching a certain regex, although I did forget to anchor said regex. I  couldn't see how to make inotify only move things that matched a pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ls $downloadDir -a1 | grep '[^.].*bin' | head -1` is the wrong way to go about this.  To see why, suppose you had files named `a.txt` and `b.bin` in the download directory, and then `c.bin` was added. `inotifywait` would print `c.bin`, `ls` would print `a.txt\nb.bin\nc.bin` (with actual newlines, not \n), `grep` would thin that to `b.bin\nc.bin`, `head` would remove all but the first line leaving `b.bin`, which would not match `c.bin`. You need to be checking `$line` to see if it ends in `.bin`, not scanning a directory listing. I'll give you three ways to do this:

First option, use grep to check `$line`, not the listing:

```
if echo "$line" | grep -q '[.]bin$'; then
```

Note that I'm using the `-q` option to supress grep's output, and instead simply letting the if command check its exit status (success if it found a match, failure if not).  Also, the RE is anchored to the end of the line, and the period is in brackets so it'll only match an actual period (normally, `.` in a regular expression matches any single character).  `\.bin$` would also work here.

Second option, use the shell's ability to edit variable contents to see if `$line` ends in `.bin`:

```
if [ "${line%.bin}" != "$line" ]; then
```

the `"${line%.bin}"` part gives the value of $line with `.bin` trimmed from the end if it's there.  If that's not the same as `$line` itself, then `$line` must've ended with `.bin`.

Third option, use bash's `[[ ]]` expression to do pattern matching directly:

```
if [[ "$line" == *.bin ]]; then
```

This is (IMHO) the simplest and clearest of the bunch, but it only works in bash (i.e. you must start the script with `#!/bin/bash`).

Other notes: to avoid some possible issues with whitespace and backslashes in filenames, use `while IFS= read -r line; do` and follow @shellter's recommendation about double-quotes religiously.

Also, I'm not very familiar with inotifywait, but AIUI its `-e create` option will notify you when the file is created, not when its contents are fully written out.  Depending on the timing, you may wind up copying partially-written files.

Finally, you don't have any checking for duplicate filenames.  What should happen if you download a file named `foo.bin`, it gets copied, you delete the original, then download a different file named `foo.bin`.  As the script is now, it'll silently overwrite the first `foo.bin`.  If this isn't what you want, you should add something like:

```
if [ ! -e "$mbedDir/$line" ]; then
    cp "$downloadDir/$line" "$mbedDir/$line"
elif ! cmp -s "$downloadDir/$line" "$mbedDir/$line"; then
    echo "Eeek, a duplicate filename!" >&2
    # or possibly something more constructive than that...
fi
```